# scala: best way to merge two mutable maps of mutable sets

Tags: scala, scala-collections

What is the best way in scala to merge two mutable maps of mutable sets?  The operation must be commutative.  The things I've tried seem ugly...

```
import scala.collection.mutable
var d1 = mutable.Map[String, mutable.SortedSet[String]]()
var d2 = mutable.Map[String, mutable.SortedSet[String]]()

// adding some elements.  Accumulating nimals with the set of sounds they make.
d1.getOrElseUpdate("dog", mutable.SortedSet[String]("woof"))
d2.getOrElseUpdate("cow", mutable.SortedSet[String]("moo"))
d2.getOrElseUpdate("dog", mutable.SortedSet[String]("woof", "bark"))
```

*magic* (that is commutative!)

```
scala.collection.mutable.Map[String,scala.collection.mutable.SortedSet[String]] =
Map(dog -> TreeSet(bark, woof), cow -> TreeSet(moo))
```

Basically, I want to override the definition for ++ to merge the sets for matching map keys.  Notice that 
    d1 ++ d2 gives the right answer, while d2 ++ d1 does not (so ++ is not commutative here).

Comment: Why mutable? Do you want to update one of the maps with the values from the other?

Comment: Thinking about it, I probably could use immutable too.  Mutable just made more sense for how I was using this.  See edit

Answer (score 3):

For every key that would be in the resulting `Map`, you have to merge (`++`) the value `Set`s from `d1` and `d2` for that key.

For `mutable.Map`s and `mutable.Set`s, when you are updating one of the `Map`s, the implementation is really straightforward:

```
for ((key, values) <- d2) 
  d1.getOrElseUpdate(key, mutable.SortedSet.empty) ++= values
```

You can actually create an empty `mutable.Map`, and use that code to update it with `d1` and `d2` (and other `Map`s if needed) in any order.

You can wrap this operation in a following function:

```
val d1 = mutable.Map[String, mutable.SortedSet[String]](
  "dog" -> mutable.SortedSet("woof"), 
  "cow" -> mutable.SortedSet("moo"))
val d2 = mutable.Map[String, mutable.SortedSet[String]](
  "dog" -> mutable.SortedSet("woof", "bark"))

def updateMap[A, B : Ordering]( // `Ordering` is a requirement for `SortedSet`
  d1: mutable.Map[A, mutable.SortedSet[B]])(
  // `Iterable`s are enough here, but allow to pass a `Map[A, Set[B]]`
  d2: Iterable[(A, Iterable[B])] 
): Unit =
  for ((key, values) <- d2)
    d1.getOrElseUpdate(key, mutable.SortedSet.empty) ++= values

// You can call 
// `updateMap(d1)(d2)` or 
// `updateMap(d2)(d1)` to achieve the same result (but in different variables)
```

---

For immutable `Map`s one possible implementation is:

```
(
  for (key <- d1.keySet ++ d2.keySet)
  yield key -> (d1.getOrElse(key, Set.empty) ++ d2.getOrElse(key, Set.empty))
).toMap
```

Other, likely more effective, but probably slightly more complex implementations are also possible.